# How do the initial conditions change if I solve $\frac{dx}{dy}$ instead of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good day,

In differential equations it is often useful to compute $\frac{dx}{dy}$, I mean if you have System like

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=xy, \frac{dy}{dt}=y, y(t_0)=y_0, x(t_0)=x_0~ (x_0,y_0>0)$$

These initial conditions are with respect to $t=t_0$.

I know how to solve this individually, first $y=y_0 e^{t-t_0}$ and then
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=xy_0e^{t-t_0} \Rightarrow \int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{x} = y_0 \int_{t_0}^t e^{t-t_0} dt \Rightarrow ln(x)-ln(x_0)=y_0 (e^{t-t_0} -1)\Rightarrow x=x_0 e^{y_0(e^{t-t_0}-1)}$$

Maybe this is not a good example because it is pretty easy this way, but if I now compute (if $x \neq 0, y\neq 0$) $$\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}=x$$
I get something like $x(y)=c e^y$. Is there an easy way to see what $x(\hat{y}_0)$ is? The initial condition for this solution. Without computing the ODEs individually like I did.

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I mean you have of course $x(y)=\hat{x}_0 e^{y-\hat{y}_0}$ for $x(\hat{y}_0)=\hat{x}_0$ but is there a way to get $\hat{y}_0, \hat{x}_0$ from the initial conditions with respect to $t_0$?

EDIT2: Okay it seems like $\hat x_0=x_0=x(t_0)$ and $\hat y_0=y_0=y(t_0)$ in this case because then I get 
$$x(y)=x_0e^{y-y_0}$$
which is the same solution as above when I am putting $y$ into it. 
Is this result always true? That the initial conditions stay the same? Or is this just a coincidence?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IVP
$$\dot x=f(x,y),\qquad\dot y=g(x,y), \quad x(t_0)=x_0,\quad y(t_0)=y_0$$
defines a motion in the plane as a process in time. The resulting curve may have vertical tangents at some points, or wind three times around the origin before going off to infinity.

Sometimes you are not interested in the exact "timetable" but only in the resulting curve $\gamma$. As such it begins at $(x_0,y_0)$, and you may assume that in the neighborhood of this point it is a graph  $x\mapsto y=y(x)$ or  $y\mapsto x=x(y)$. In the first case this function $x\mapsto y(x)$ satisfies the ODE
$$y'={g(x,y)\over f(x,y)}\qquad\left(={\dot y\over\dot x}\right)$$
and the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$, of course.